# Ajax.Request not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below ajax request working in all browsers but not in chrome version 28.XX.  Someone please tell me,what is wrong with this code?

```
     var output = '';

      $.ajax({
        url      : "PageController/CurrencyController.php",
        data     : formData,
        dataType : "text",        
        async    : false,
        success  : function(html, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                   alert(" ajax done"+html);
            if ( html != '' ) {
                output = html;
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Req "+XMLHttpRequest +" status "+textStatus+"  Error "+errorThrown);
        }
});
```

`alert(" ajax done"+html);` does not work in Chrome but gives popup in other browsers.

Comment: Its probably because it does not succeed. Are you sure it hits the server code correctly.

Comment: Yes. because it works perfectly in FF & safari ...etc

Comment: what is the use of having ajax with async=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is using `XMLHttpRequest` as a function parameter name.  That is a reserved word.  Try changing it `xhr`.

```
 var output = '';

 $.ajax({
    url      : "PageController/CurrencyController.php",
    data     : formData,
    dataType : "text",        
    async    : false,
    success  : function(html, textStatus, xhr) {
        alert(" ajax done"+html);
        if ( html != '' ) {
            output = html;
        }
    },
    error    : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("Req "+xhr+" status "+textStatus+"  Error "+errorThrown);
    }
});
```

[More about XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Your suggestion worked but actually problem was with chrome 28.xx